# Why are props being shared between seperate instances of an emotion-js component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emotion

1. Why does emotion-js appear to share the props from seperate component instances?

```
<Button isDisabled={'true'} />
<Button />
```

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: ${props => props.isDisabled !== 'true' ? 'green' : 'grey'};
`;
```

```
export default (props) => {
    return (<Button>Hello</Button>);
}
```

**Expectation:** The first `<Button/>` is grey. The second is green.

**Reality**: Both instances of `<Button/>` are grey.

---

Also, this one had me very confused until I noticed this snippit from the docs:

> By default, Emotion passes all props to custom components and only props that are valid html attributes for string tags.

2. Why pass **only** props that are valid string tags? The following use of `bool` seems like it would be a valid use case.

```
<Button isDisabled={true} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not share props. You just need to pass them properly.
There are two ways to achieve what you want, either do it with proper strings or with boolean values:

String version:

```
const Button = styled('button')`
  background-color: ${props => props.isDisabled !== 'true' ? 'green' : 'grey'};
`;
```

Usage:

```
<Button isDisabled="true">grey</Button>
<Button>green</Button>
```

Or with bool values (what might be preferable in this case):

```
const Button = styled('button')`
  background-color: ${props => props.isDisabled ? 'grey' : 'green'};
`;
```

Usage:

```
<Button isDisabled>Grey</Button>
<Button>green</Button>
```